# Sublime text 2 is not working Showing error after installing package control

Tags: plugins, ide, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

After running this code on sublime text 2 Console from https://packagecontrol.io

```
import urllib2,os,hashlib; 
h = 'eb2297e1a458f27d836c04bb0cbaf282' + 'd0e7a3098092775ccb37ca9d6b2e4b7d'; 
pf = 'Package Control.sublime-package'; 
ipp = sublime.installed_packages_path(); 
os.makedirs( ipp ) if not os.path.exists(ipp) else None; 
urllib2.install_opener( urllib2.build_opener( urllib2.ProxyHandler()) ); 
by = urllib2.urlopen( 'http://packagecontrol.io/' + pf.replace(' ', '%20')).read(); 
dh = hashlib.sha256(by).hexdigest(); 
open( os.path.join( ipp, pf), 'wb' ).write(by) if dh == h else None; 
print('Error validating download (got %s instead of %s), please try manual install' % (dh, h) if dh != h else 'Please restart Sublime Text to finish installation')
```

Sublime is giving me this error

```
---------------------------
Sublime Text 2
---------------------------
Unable to run package setup:

Failed to load module

ImportError: No module named PackageSetup
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a manual install.

Instructions as per [Package Control Installation page](https://packagecontrol.io/installation#st2):

> If for some reason the console installation instructions do not work for you (such as having a proxy on your network), perform the following steps to manually install Package Control:
>
> 1. Click the `Preferences > Browse Packages…` menu
> 2. Browse up a folder and then into the `Installed Packages/` folder
> 3. Download [Package Control.sublime-package](https://packagecontrol.io/Package%20Control.sublime-package) and copy it into the `Installed Packages/` directory
> 4. Restart Sublime Text

Comment: But the sublime is not running at all ! just giving me an error massage and finish !

Comment: Have a look in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Installed Packages` and if there is a `Package Control.sublime-package` file, remove it and then try a manual install

Comment: thanks for reply there is no file called`Package Control.sublime-package` in installed packages :(

Comment: Ok. Then try a manual install of the Package Control as I mentioned above. If this still fails (or Sublime Text fails to open without an error) then maybe you need to reinstall Sublime Text - and upgrade to version 3 while you're at it.

Comment: uninstall and reinstall it and the same error bro !

Comment: what OS are you running?

Comment: Also found this thread which may help [http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4025#p18569](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4025#p18569)

Comment: thanks bro i just uninstall it before reinstall i just delete all the Appdata and `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2` directory file and it work's for me